# PHP: тип переменной

Tags: php, mysql

Функция получает некую переменную, которая может быть двух видов - массивом и результатом выборки данных из БД (функцией mysql_query)

Требуется определить тип переменной (для того, что бы, если это данные и БД, преобразовать их в ассоциативный массив)

Каким образом это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(is_array($var)){
  //do something with array;
}else{
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($var,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    //do something with mysql_array
  }
}
```